# Refreshing information in Node.js from filesystem with jade template engine

Tags: node.js, yaml, pug

I'm currently writing a node.js app currently using: express, jade, and js-yaml. The YAML parser loads the file that I need to load easily.

```
require('js-yaml');

var file = require(path);
```

The contents of the file that I need to get information from is then loaded into the jade template.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index', { pageData: contents });
});
```

Now my problem is that when the information in the YAML file changes, i want the information on the node.js server to update, or refresh the information. As of right now, it loads one time, but that's it. Is there a way to either create a listener or some other type of function to update the information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use fs.watchFile() to watch the file for changes and load them as the file changes.  You could also use setInterval, to update based on some time inteval.

```
fs.watchFile(fileName, [array of options], function callback() {
    //Whatever actions parse your yaml file here
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful with what I needed, but I realized with what I was using I couldn't do _exactly_ what I wanted, but this is now helping me immensely. :3